# Redirecting log from /var/log/kern.log to a separate log file for iptables log

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.04, rsyslog

I am trying to redirect iptables log to another file. Based upon my reading on the net, I did the following:

In my iptables rule, I have rules like:

iptables -A INPUT -s ... -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables@@"
Then in the folder /etc/rsyslog.d, I created a file with the entries:

:msg,contains,"iptables@@" /var/log/iptables.log
 & ~
I also tried to have a blank line between the above two lines. I do get the iptables log entries now going to iptables.log file. But they ALSO go to /var/log/kern.log file. I want to suppress the later. How do I do this. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Have you restarted rsyslog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your **/etc/rsyslog.conf** loads yours *.conf in **/etc/rsyslog.d**, it reads your files alphabetically. So, you need to make sure that your rules are in a file that comes before 50-default.conf, like:

```
01-myiptablesrules.conf
```

This way, your rules will be read first, and discard it. You should also use this syntax:

```
:msg, contains, "iptables@@" {
  *.* /var/log/iptables.log
  stop
}
```

*You should use stop instead of ~

Or if you don't have others kern.* than your iptables messages, you should modify **50-default.conf** with:

```
kern.*            /var/log/iptables.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a line in your rsyslog config files that prints the message to `/var/log/kern.log`?  If so, post that code.  Also post your rsyslog verison number.  In the meantime, this could work:

```
:msg,contains,"iptables@@"             /var/log/iptables.log
:msg,contains,"iptables@@"             ~
```

Though I believe once you do that second line, rsyslog will disregard all messages containing `iptables@@` so it can't be logged elsewhere (after that line).